# How to make API map markers appear when a certain condition is true

Tags: javascript, html

I need to edit my code so that if a user enter a certain word specific markers would appear and the same with a different out put and so on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the event and do stuff
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event